# Which partitions are my OS installed on?

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10, 20.04, boot-partition

I previously have Ubuntu-19.10 in C drive then I installed Kubuntu-20.04 with option guided partition. And I think 19.10 is also present in HDD and I want to remove it.

[This is screenshot of my partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sorUe.png)

[image: KDE Partition]

Comment: You didn't run `fdisk` in a manner helpful (you only have permission denied errors because you didn't raise your privileges using `sudo`).  The diskfree (`df`) command only shows mounted drives, where mounted drives are all located on 'sda' (serial ATA or SCSI) drive A  (the C label is a legacy name label by CP/M/DOS/windows where the first SDA drive is called C for historical reasons; A and B being reserved for floppies usually). I'm not sure we can provide you with an *useful* answer given what you've given us.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Please check again I edited the image.Thanks.

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, copy & paste the text into your question (pictures make sense if you provided a picture from KDE Partition Manager, or `gparted`)

Comment: okay. this is all new for me. learning slowly slowly.